# Running a SFML C++ program with minGW on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, sfml

So I'm trying to run an example SFML program on my Windows laptop. If relevant, the source code is on [this page.](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-linux.php)

So first I make the .o file using this command -

```
g++ -c a.cpp -ISFML/SFML/include
```

Where a.cpp is the main file, and my SFML package is located in SFML/SFML.

Then I compile using this command -

```
g++ a.o -o a -LSFML/SFML/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

When I first ran the program I got the errors about not being able to find certain dlls, sfml-graphics-2 etc. So I found them and put them next to the exe. But now when I run, I get this weird error:

> The procedure entry point 
>   _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringSt11char_traitsIcESalcEE7reserveEj could not be located in the dynamic link library.

What is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you enable compiling to the C++11 Standard by adding `-std=c++11` to the command lines?

Comment: Are you using the correct libs and dll for your compiler? This sounds more like you're using incorrect ones.

Comment: @Rosme it's the windows 32 download from the official site

Comment: As [the SFML download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/) states and what @Rosme is asking, the operating system isn't the main concern. You could be using the wrong version of the compiler, some old libraries of SFML, etc. Worst case, if your compiler is not listed there, you have to compile SFML yourself.

Comment: @Chringo if you don't mind helping me out, how would I compile sfml by myself

Comment: Get [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/). Get the source code for 2.4.2 by going to the bottom of [the download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/). Follow [this guide on SFML's GitHub repo](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Build-SFML-with-a-MinGW-Compiler). Alternatively, you could use [the guide on SFML's page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php) but it is for an older version. Perhaps it answers gaps that the first one misses? Also, ones CMake have generated the makefiles you're on your way to build SFML. Good luck!

Comment: @Chringo This is a good answer. Please post it as an answer, so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Have you had any progress @JosephLong ?

Answer (score 1):

As [the SFML download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/) states, You could be using the wrong version of the compiler, other library versions of SFML that you have not removed from your working directory that could mismatch between code and linker. Worst case, if your compiler is not listed there, you have to compile SFML yourself:
Get [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/). Get the source code for 2.4.2 by going to the bottom of the SFML download page. Follow [this guide on SFML's GitHub repo](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Build-SFML-with-a-MinGW-Compiler). Alternatively, you could use [the guide on SFML's page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php) but it is for an older version. It might answer some questions that the first guide misses.
Ones CMake have generated the makefiles, you're on your way to build SFML.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem for so long so I just wanted to help someone out who had the same problem. I have a windows 10 FYI and MinGW-w64 8.1.0 (if it doesnt work try a 32 bit mingw instead)

for a debug mode (debug is when your still working on the game and would like command prompt to open whenever you run it)

(make sure your in the right directory first by doing "cd")

```
g++ -c (file_name).cpp -o (file_name).o -I(path_to)SFML-64-bit/include -g -m64 -Wall &&
 g++ (file_name).o -o (game_name).exe -L(path_to)SFML-64-bit/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

The code above when placed in command will compile everything for you if its all in the same directory so make sure you keep an eye out for that

and now for release mode (if you dont want command prompt to show up)

```
g++ -c (file_name).cpp -o (file_name).o -I(path_to)SFML-64-bit/include -O3 -m64 &&
 g++ (file_name).o -o (game_name).exe -L(path_to)SFML-64-bit/lib -lsfml-graphics lsfml-window -lsfml-system -mwindows
```

Noticed all I added was the -mwindows and the -O3 aswell as removing -g and -Wall which are not necessary since we wont be using command prompt

Make sure to go to SFML/bin and take all the .dlls and put it into the same directory has your .exe sorry xd

Hope this helped.